# Как сделать перебор чисел в пайтон для телеграмм (python)

Tags: python, telebot

кто читает данное сообщение
Пытался найти свой вопрос, но нигде не нашёл и решил прийти сюда.
На одном канале увидел как автор перебирает числа при помощи

```
if message.text in "0123456789":
```

Я хотел бы узнать как сделать перебор для больших чисел, например миллиона и т.д.

Comment: `int(message.text) in range(a, b)`

Comment: Я так пытался делать, но мне нужен чтобы можно было сделать цикл:

if int(message.text) in range(a, b)
else:
bot.send_message(message.chat.id, "Вы ввели текст")

Comment: В заголовке "перебор", в теле проверка. Что вы хотите? Покажите пример.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
def foo(text):
    if text.isdigit():
        print("цифры")
    else:
        print("текст")

foo("28394832222")
foo("283948иии22")
```

Результат:

```
цифры
текст
```